# How to fix the my Anchor link issue

Tags: html, css

**EDIT: From my previous post, none of the answers can satisfy my needs so I created a jsfiddle here to be more clear.**

I am having an issue about my anchor tag.

I have created a `jsfiddle`

http://jsfiddle.net/7tMy5/

When I click my links, it will jump to the contents div. However, it seems like the content div is covered by the header div which has position:fixed specified. I want the contents jump to below my header div. How do I fix this?

I can't really change the my header div css property here...

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your code seems to work as designed here. It would be very useful to just cut the `position: fixed`. You don't really need it.

Comment: I know JoshC. I just created a jsfiddle here for people to look at. I am really desperate now.

Comment: I will need the position:fixed because my other contents need to have it.

Comment: @FlyingCat Maybe just cut the height down on `#header`. This would make the content show more. About making it jump below `#header`, You would need it to jump to a specific place. To me it sounds complicated.

Comment: @JJP I can't cut down the height of the header. that's the problem..:(

Comment: @FlyingCat [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZKpy/). I just cut down the size. What browser are you using?

Comment: @JJP chrome. I need to show the full size of the header which is 200px.

Comment: The solution I posted on your original question works - http://jsfiddle.net/ZFDUF/

Comment: @FlyingCat Why? You don't even have one full line of text. You are pretty much wasting space in `#header`

Comment: My jsfiddle is just for demo purpose. I can't really put all my contents in jsfiddle.

Comment: Creating a new question is not the way to get more attention on your problem. Edit your original question with the new information and try giving out [bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @JoshC could you please modify my jsfiddle? My brain really fried now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/7tMy5/8/ I got this code from http://www.pixelflips.com/blog/anchor-links-with-a-fixed-header/ check it out and see if this is what you wanted to achieve

```
<span class="anchor" id="section1"></span>
<div class="section"></div>

<span class="anchor" id="section2"></span>
<div class="section"></div>

<span class="anchor" id="section3"></span>
<div class="section"></div>
```

This is pretty much the new html markup for the page

Comment: I want to give you a hug if you are next to me.